# ¿Cómo configurar uuid postgres BD en hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

En la base de datos tengo el campo `usr_id` con `uuid_generate_v4()` por default para crear automaticamente el uuid. ¿como utilizo hibernate para que tome el uuid que se genera en la BD?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User extends DateAudit {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = -4023299907867915572L;

     @Id
     @Column(name="usr_id")
     @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="pg-uuid")
     private UUID id;
   }
```

> `Error:`
>          ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

NO quiero crear el UUID desde el backend. Deseo utilizar el que se crea por default en la BD.

Comment: @theboshy  how resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es utilizar el **uuid** desde el mapeo de la entidad, *si, es necesario generarlo desde el backend*, de cualquier forma para **evitar** añadirlo *manualmente* como indica el error puedes inyectar una *dependencia* para autogenerarlo de la misma forma en la que lo hace la base de datos.

con `@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")`

```
 @Id
 @Column(name="usr_id")
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="pg-uuid")
 @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid4")
 private UUID id;
```

> En este caso con la estrategia de generacion v4 (**strategy = "uuid4"**)

Para especificar la estrategia de generacion o

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
```

para generarlo con al configuracion de **hibernate**.

La specificacion para generadores adicionales la encuentras [aca](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5294).

> Si necesita UUID compatibles con RFC 4122, considere usar el generador "uuid2"

Comment: no funciono. debo primero crear el UUID para poder guardar la entidad u objeto. no se crea automaticamente.